# Android Swipe Views Ethernet AndroidPlot & Overall Architecture

Tags: tabs, udp, fragment, androidplot

I'm quite new to Android development.

I'm trying to write an app that communicates by Wifi using UDP to an instrument.

The app plots 512 bytes of data it receives over WiFi using AndroidPlot. Transfer rate is satisfactory and communications is fault tolerant.

I would now like to turn my proof of concept into a functional app complete with tabs & swipe navigation.

On one tab I'd have my chart, on another tab I'd have some controls, and another tab with status information. Each tab would need access to the UDP thread.

As I'm new to this I'm having a hard time determining the right architecture to implement.

I feel I've wasted a good bit of time on fragments and pager adapters without really getting the functionality I'm after (the work I've done so far feels as though I'm trying to force something to do what it really isn't meant to do).

Could someone with experience give me a general path to take? Are fragments the answer? Is there a way to support swiped tabs without the additional complication of fragments?

Thanks for any help! Hopefully this isn't too general.

Comment: Could you try to boil this text down to the core question? It makes it easier to answer and more useful for others. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve